# Issue with docker on mac terminal: ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker

I am having this error message when running docker-compose or any docker command:
`ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issue is linked to the fact that I have changed my username to a new username. `/var/run/docker.sock`is a symlink to `/Users/USERNAME/.docker/run/docker.sock`
`/var/run/docker.sock@ -> /Users/OLD USER NAME/.docker/run/docker.sock`